# How to properly Insert audio and video files in an HTML document using the object tag

Tags: html

My instructor wants me to practice inserting audio and video files using the object tag. However, I can't seem to get the code right no matter how many times I delete it and try something different each time. I know how to add them with the audio and video tags I just can't seem to do it with the object tag. Can someone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong? Here is what my code currently looks like for my audio html document:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

 <html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <title>Kana-audio</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
 </head>

 <body>

 <div style="text-align: center">
    <img src="Japanese.png" width="500" height="400" alt="Japanese Language" />
    <h2 >Basics of Japanese: Hiragana & Katakana</h2>


</div>


 <div style="text-align: center">
    <ul>
        <li class="navlist"><a href="The Japanese Language.html"><span  class="boldword">Home</span></a> &nbsp; | &nbsp; 
        <li class="navlist"><a href="Kana-pictures.html">Pictures</a> &nbsp; | &nbsp;
        <li class="navlist"><a href="Kana-video.html">Video</a> &nbsp; | &nbsp; 
        <li class="navlist"><a href="Kana-audio.html">Audio</a> 
    </ul>
</div>

<h1 style="text-align: center; color: #FF0000 ; font-size: xx-large;">Kana-audio </h1>

<div class="Object">

   <object type="audio/mp3" data="Kana Sounds.mp3" width="250" height="45" autoplay="false">

<param name="src" value="Kana Sounds.mp3" />
<param name="controller" value="true" /> 
<param name="autoplay" value="false" />
<param name="autostart" value="0" />

</object>
</div>

<div class="content">
    <p>In this audio file each kana (hiragana & katakana) character is pronounced slowly to ensure that the proper sound is heard.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: is the song available at the same directory, try to rename the file to kana_sounds.mp3 and try it

Comment: Yes it is in the same directory, thanks I'll try that!

Comment: hmm nothing changes still...any other suggestions?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/NcVCdh here is the sample code which runs a mp3 song can you give me the directory structure of your song

Comment: okay it goes: This PC>Documents>Spring 2017 Semester>HTML Class work>ChapterFiles>Chapter08

Comment: try to give the entire directory location under the data, after renaming the file have you changed the data:"Kana Songs.mp3" to data:"Kana_Songs.mp3"

Comment: hmm I don't know if I've done that right or not, either way nothings changing for me? Also I did rename it as well for the data section. Is there anyway I could just show you my whole folder containing all the related documents and audio & video files for this web site I've made? Would it help if I could?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you link to "Kana_Songs.mp3" from the page and click the link does the MP3 play? or do you get an error?

If it does not play, it will not play in the object tag either.

The Object tag are basicly iframe tags that allow parameters.

These are essentially the same but with some differences in overhead taken by the browser to render them.

```
<iframe src="scripted.xhtml?paramname1=value1" sandbox="allow-scripts">
</iframe>

<object data="scripted.xhtml" data-sandbox="allow-scripts">
    <param name="paramname1" value="value1" />
</object>

<embed src="scripted.xhtml?paramname1=value1" data-sandbox="allow-scripts">
</embed>
```

The **type="audio/mp3"** from the server may be

```
.mp3    audio/mpeg3
.mp3    audio/x-mpeg-3
.mp3    video/mpeg
.mp3    video/x-mpeg
```

It is not required on the object tag but is used. if the song plays from the link but not the object. Right click the browser, go inspect element, go to the network tab and see what the browser is actually using as the type.

Comment: note autoplay is not used in html5 ... media files that the browser knows how to play are automatically played when they are directly linked to. classid is also not supported in html5, the browser will decide the program it will use to play the mimi type, (pdf, mp3, mp4, html). You don't get script control unless you use the audio tag, which is what you would do in the real world.

Comment: If you are uploading it to a web server, the mp3 must be uploaded in binary format.